# Including ansible vars without override, but append to dict

Tags: ansible

Im loading 2 ansible vars `defaults.yml` and `prod.yml` in that order (which is overriding). is there any way to append keys of prod to existing dict of defaults (instead of overriding) ?

`defaults.yml`

```
sdpbroker:
  tenants:
    messaging_manager_init_retry_interval: 30000
```

`prod.yml`

```
sdpbroker:
  tenants:
  - id: 7
    messaging_manager_init_retry_interval: 7000
```

the wanted result is a combined dict, ie:

```
sdpbroker:
  tenants:
    messaging_manager_init_retry_interval: 30000
    - id: 7
      messaging_manager_init_retry_interval: 7000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR` in your Ansible configuration to `merge` will merge dictionaries instead of replacing them:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/reference_appendices/config.html

I'm currently using this to only provide (read: overwrite) certain values  in a large dictionary.

Comment: thanks jan, is it possible to do with lists also (ie, append to list and not override) ?

Comment: I'm wondering, whether this has some undesired side-effects, e.g. in community roles that expect the behavior to be non-merge?